# Log4net parou de mostrar os logs

Tags: c#

Meu console parou de mostrar os logs do nada, já compilei várias vezes e nunca me aconteceu isso, só agora

Código:

```
    public static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

log.Info("Hello World")
```

O Hello World não aparece, mas se eu fizer Console.WriteLine("Hello World") aparece no console, oque pode ser? Queria que voltasse a aparecer o log.Info.

Será que pode ser algum bug?

Algumas vezes aparece só os log.error:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deve estar faltando alguma configuração aí no seu app, coloquei detalhado na minha resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem 3 itens que você precisa checar.

1- App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

  </log4net>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

2- Assemblyinfo.cs

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

3- Seu Programa:

```
    public static class Program
    {
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            log.Error("Hello World");
            log.Warn("Hello World");
            log.Info("Hello World");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Pronto :)
[image: Exemplo]

Código fonte do meu teste:

https://github.com/thiagoloureiro/Log4Net

Comment: Eu queria que fosse igual ao meu edit, teria como?

Comment: não entendi.. o que tem o seu Edit ? a data? aí é o formato que voce define nas configurações do log..
Aqui oh 
<conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />